# element.remove doesn't execute after success $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive to check if the user has the right role to view a certain element.

This is my directive :

```
angular.module("BlurAdmin")
.directive('restrict',restrict);
    function restrict (authService, $http, $state){
    return{
       restrict: 'A',
       prioriry: 100000,
       scope: false,
       link: function(){
 },
       compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
         var accessDenied = true;

         var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");

         var getCurrentUser = function () {

           authService.getCurrentUser()
                .success(function (data) {
                    var user = data;
                    for(var i in attributes){
                      if(user.roles[0].name == attributes[i]){
                          accessDenied = false;
                      }
                    };
                    if(accessDenied){
                        element.children().remove();
                        element.remove();
                    };
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    $state.go("/login");
                });
    };
            getCurrentUser();
  }

 }
}
```

As you see I'm calling the `element.remove` in the success callback of async call `$http` that way I can be sure that the `element.remove` is excuted after I get the roles, **BUT** weirdly the element is not removed [and I've tested it, I can bypass the if condition) .

And If I try the **same directive with a static values** the element **IS** getting removed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT :**

If you have any alternative to this solution be my guest.

Comment: Are you sure that the `element.remove()` is called? If so, can you check again the `if` condition inside the `for` loop. `if(user.roles[0].name == attributes[i]){`.

Comment: Yes I've check the `accessDenied` variable is changing from `true` to `false` I've done all the checks the code runs perfectly but the `element.remove` and I've put a `console.log()` inside the `if` statement and it's getting executed. this is what is driving me crazy, everything is ok...

Comment: When do you want to remove the element? If you want to remove the element when the `accessDenied` is true, then in your case, as you said `accessDenied` is changing from `true` to `false`, then how will the if condition pass?

Comment: I want to remove the element when `accessDenied=true` it means that the user dosen't have the required role[that's the purpose of the `for` loop]

Comment: In your condition then `accessDenied` is becoming false hence it is not removed.

Comment: it's not always false, I mentionned that to proove that everything works as excepted as in my test I implemented the directive in two element one wich the user need to have access and the other he doesn't have access